# What's wrong with my php/mysql code?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm toying around with a kind of blog. I'm getting an error and when I say:

My PHP is as follows:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO articles (articleTitle, articleType, articleText, userID)
        VALUES('$articleTitle', '$articleType', '$articleText', '$userID')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    var_dump($articleTitle);
    var_dump($articleType);
    var_dump($articleText);
    var_dump($userID);

    var_dump($result);

    echo mysql_error();
```

my result is this:

```
    string 'New News! (Sounds like noo noo's)' (length=33)
    string 'News' (length=4)
    string 'NEWS is here! This is Michael Bender reporting on the new news that we now have news! Isn't that exciting news?' (length=111)
    string '1' (length=1)
    boolean false
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's)', 'News', 'NEWS is here! This is Michael Bender reporting on
>   the new news tha' at line 2

So why won't the mysql accept my query? Thanks!

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` family of functions. Use `PDO` (best) or the `mysqli_*` functions (less good).

Comment: The error tells you exactly where the error is (`near s)'`), your error is the ' which is escaping your string. Fix it by inserting an \ before the '

Comment: Right. Sorry to have missed that. Thanks for your help all! I knew it was something stupid.

Comment: In such cases, just echo your query and try to execute it in phpmyadmin or on MySQL terminal directly. You will soon be able to get a clue.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape all the variables passed to mysql_query with `mysql_real_escape_string`. Also, you may want to use PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that will break your query:

> string 'New News! (Sounds like noo noo's)' (length=33)

the single quote `'`

You will need to escape your values before using them in your query. Or you will be victim of [Sql Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO articles (articleTitle, articleType, articleText, userID)
        VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', %d)";

$query = sprintf($query,
   mysql_real_escape_string($articleTitle),
   mysql_real_escape_string($articleType), 
   mysql_real_escape_string($articleText), 
   (int) $userID); // assuming your userId is an integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_real_escape_string() on your data, as it will prevent your queries from crashing because they contain special characters.